# How to render variables into a target file from differnet dotenv environment files like envsubst

Tags: shell, kubernetes, environment-variables

I have all my env vars in .env files.
They get automatically loaded when I open my shell-terminal.

I normally render shell environment variables into my target files with `envsubst`. similar to the example below.

#### What I search is a solution where I can pass a `dotenv`-file as well my `template`-file to a script which outputs the rendered result.

Something like this:

```
aScript --input .env.production --template template-file.yml --output result.yml
```

I want to be able to parse different environment variables into my yaml. The output should be sealed via "Sealed secrets" and finally saved in the regarding kustomize folder

```
envsub.sh .env.staging templates/secrets/backend-secrets.yml | kubeseal -o yaml > kustomize/overlays/staging
```

I hope you get the idea.

---

example

`.env.production`-file:

FOO=bar
PASSWROD=abc

content of `template-file.yml`

```
stringData:
  foo: $FOO
  password: $PASSWORD
```

Then running this:

```
envsubst < template-file.yml > file-with-vars.yml
```

the result is:

```
stringData:
  foo: bar
  password: abc
```

My approach so far does not work because Dotenv also supports **different environments** like `.env`, `.env.production`, `.env.staging` asf..

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:kubernetes], though it's not totally clear how it's connected.  If you need to fill in values in Kubernetes YAML files, have you looked at tools like Helm or Kustomize that are designed to support install-time configuration?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes I also use Kustomize, but parsing different environments into secrets is not supported (for example with `envsubst`. Now I am able to run the accepted solution like so: `templates/envsub.sh ./.env.staging ./templates/secrets/backend-secrets.yml|kubeseal -o yaml > kustomize/overlays/staging`. I will add that use case in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
#!/bin/sh

# envsub - subsitute environment variables

env=$1
template=$2

sh -c "
. \"$env\"

cat <<EOF
$(cat "$template")
EOF"
```

Usage:

```
./envsub .env.production template-file.yaml > result.yaml
```

- A here-doc with an unquoted delimiter (`EOF`) expands variables, whilst preserving quotes, backslashes, and other shell sequences.
- `sh -c` is used like `eval`, to expand the command substitution, then run that output through a here-doc.
- Be aware that this extra level of indirection creates potential for code injection, if someone can modify the yaml file.

For example, adding this:

```
EOF
echo malicous commands
```

But it does get the result you want.

Comment: wow.... I knew it could be simply written, but that's really lean.  Thank you.